# Sql developer-Oracle Database 11g connection failed

Tags: oracle

I have downloaded Oracle database11g(32 bit)and SQL developer.When i tried for a connection from sql developer to database i'm getting the following error.

"The Network could not establish the connection."

I have also checked for listener status thinking it might me the cause but when I tried to execute the command on cmd

SQL>lsnrctl start

I'm getting lsnrctl is not an internal/external command.

what should i do now?

Comment: Looks like you're trying to run "lsnrctl" from within Oracle. It's not an Oracle, sql*plus command, it's an o/s level utility/command. Are you in Unix or Windows? Where is the Oracle instance installed? You need to run lsnrctl from an id on the same server as the oracle instance and who has their Oracle env properly installed.

Answer (score 0):

I would follow the below steps in narrowing this down:

- Have you installed the oracle 32 bit client application (currently located [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/instant-client/index-097480.html) ). For future, a simple Google for "oracle 11g instant client 32-bit". Personally I would go with an instant client.

  - are you using a TNSNames.ora file? if so check you have an environment variable set up called "TNS_Admin" on your pc. Again a simple google for "Setting an Oracle Connection to Use TNSNames.ora" should find you detailed instructions on how to do this.
  - If after all this nothing works, please update the question with more details, and perhaps try another Oracle Client (toad free trial etc) to establish the problem is not specific to Oracle Sql Developer.